# make-frame-on-display & emacsclient fail w/ exported display while other apps are fine

Tags: frames, emacsclient, ssh, x11

I am connecting to my office GNU/Linux box from a windows laptop through a putty ssh tunnel.

I have also on the laptop the java WeirdX X11 server, that is declared in putty to use the `localhost:2` (default) display, while the "enable X11 forwarding" is enabled.

Once connected on my Linux, the X11 export seems correctly configured by putty with `DISPLAY=localhost:10.0` as I can start `xlogo`, `xeyes` or even Firefox.

But when invoking `emacsclient -c` I get the following error:

```
Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Display localhost:10.0 can't be opened
```

For what I understand, `emacsclient` finds the running Emacs (confirmed if I use `emacsclient -nw`: I can get my running emacs session) but Emacs cannot use my distant display.

And when I join my session with `emacsclient -nw` then `M-x make-frame-on-display RET localhost:10.0` I get the same

> Display localhost:10.0 can't be opened

Do you have some tip that can help?